# If the imaginary part of an entire function is never zero, the function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)\neq0\} $ entire . Show that $f$ is constant.

I took $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ and I think that g is bounded, therefore it is constant (due to Louville's theorem) but how do I prove it? Is $|g(z)|=\frac{1}{|f(z)|}=\frac{1}{u^2+v^2}\le M$ valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other way: this is a simple application of [Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) if do you know it.

Comment: Can I claim that because $f$ misses more than a single point , but is entire by definition , then i can't be non-constant?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an outline for you to fill in:

- Since $f$ is continuous, its image must lie either in the upper or lower half-plane.
- If $f(\Bbb{C})$ lies in the upper half-plane, you can compose it with the [Cayley transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Conformal_map) to get an entire function whose image fits in the unit disc. If it lies in the lower half-plane, you can do something similar.
- Liouville!

Comment: Regarding the second bullet point, $1/(f+i)$ or $1/(f-i)$ would work.